# Icons showing as squares

Tags: javascript, html, css, font-awesome

I have used Metronic admin theme panel. I have called three script for that. HTML code for icon is `<i class="icon-home"></i>`

**Script**

```
<link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,300,600,700&subset=all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/simple-line-icons/2.3.2/css/simple-line-icons.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

But icon showing up as squares.

[image]

**HTML Code**

```
<li <?php echo ($module == 'dashboard') ? 'class="nav-item active"' : ''; ?>>
    <a href="include.php?page=d-dashboard" class="nav-link nav-toggle">
      <i class="icon-home"></i>
      <span class="title">Dashboard</span>
      <span class="selected"></span>
      <span class="arrow"></span>
    </a>
</li>
```

Above script is working on font but does not working on icon.

**Simple Line Icon URL:** 
http://keenthemes.com/preview/metronic/theme/admin_1/ui_icons.html

Simple Line icon does not working on above html code.

Comment: Try by restarting your browser.

Comment: Please show us an example of the HTML you used to place the icons.

Comment: There is no way we could know what it's wrong with just this code .... seems like the font or img for the icons doesn't load .. so

Comment: This happens when the font files aren't being loaded. The html and css are right but if the font isn't there the font icon won't load. You also forgot the font-awesome "fa" class before the icon class. Example: <i class="fa fa-home"></i>. Cheatsheet for font awesome here: http://fontawesome.io/cheatsheet/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've made my comment into an answer...

You forgot the font-awesome "fa" class before the icon class. Example:

```html
<i class="fa fa-home"></i>
```

Cheatsheet for font awesome here: http://fontawesome.io/cheatsheet/ to see all the other classes for all the icons.

Comment: Simple Line Icons don't require an `fa` prefix.

Comment: Yes but the font awesome icons do. Do you have a URL we can look at?

Comment: That's great! Glad I could be of service.

Answer (score 0):

Both are working fine. Can you please give us full live code?

```html
<link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,300,600,700&subset=all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/simple-line-icons/2.3.2/css/simple-line-icons.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<p>Font awesome <i class="fa fa-trash"></i></p>
<p>Simple Line Icons <i class="icon-call-out icons"></i></p>
```

Comment: Isn't this more of a comment than an answer?

Comment: I just would like to show him working example, so maybe he can correct himself if something is wrong with his code. FYI, I also comment there.